# How to create TabItem indicator with bottom padding

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-view, android-tablayout

[image]
I want to implement a Tab Indicator with bottom margin

`<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout android:id="@+id/tabs" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:tabIndicator="@drawable/sui_tab_indicator" app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/black" app:tabIndicatorGravity="bottom" app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false" app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp" app:tabMode="scrollable" />`

Used this TabItem with indicator drawable

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> <item android:end="6dp" android:start="6dp"> <shape android:shape="rectangle"> <corners android:radius="5dp" /> <solid android:color="@color/black" /> </shape> </item> </layer-list>`

Answer (score 0):

```
Create a new drawable resource file for your tab indicator custom_tab_indicator.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Background rectangle with padding -->
    <item android:top="0dp" android:left="6dp" android:right="6dp" android:bottom="6dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- Bottom border without padding -->
    <item android:top="0dp" android:left="6dp" android:right="6dp" android:bottom="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>

Then, set this drawable as the tab indicator in your TabLayout:
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabIndicator="@drawable/custom_tab_indicator"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/black"
    app:tabIndicatorGravity="bottom"
    app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
    app:tabMode="scrollable" />

As a result, a Tab Indicator with bottom padding should appear. As required for your design, change the padding settings.
```

Comment: The tab indicator is not visible

Comment: It appears that  custom_tab_indicator.xml file's padding settings may be the problem. More specifically, the indicator may be buried because of the padding values for the first item (background rectangle with padding). adjust the padding parameters.